# What's the cleanest way to write a non-blocking for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, event-loop

So, I've been thinking about a brain teaser - what if I had a large object I for some reason had to iterate through in node js, and didn't want to block the event loop while I was doing that?

Here's an off-the-top-of-my-head example, I'm sure it can be much cleaner:

```
var forin = function(obj,callback){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj),
        index = 0,
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(index < keys.length){
                callback(keys[index],obj[keys[index]],obj);
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            index ++;
        },0);
}
```

While I'm sure there are other reasons for it being messy, this will execute slower than a regular for loop, because setInterval 0 doesn't actually execute every 0 ms, but I'm not sure how to make a loop with the much faster process.nextTick.

In my tests, I found this example takes 7 ms to run, as opposed to a native for loop (with hasOwnProperty() checks, logging the same info), which takes 4 ms.

So, what's the cleanest/fastest way to write this same code using node.js?

Comment: Why? This is abuse. Don't do this

Comment: @Raynos - Why is this abuse? If I iterate through a giant object with a native for loop, I block the thread for as long as the loop takes to execute. That sounds like abuse to me, if I take 25ms to serve every user, that can translate to a huge scaling issue.

Comment: @Jesse yes, the problem is your iteration over a giant object in javascript, why are you doing CPU intensive computation in javascript

Comment: Maybe everyone missed the last line, this is being done in node.js, not on the client. Iterating over large objects is something I would fully expect a server to be capable of without slowing down, and made asynchronous, it is a perfectly reasonable use case in node.

Comment: I don't see it as a crime to do something like this on the server, especially if you are yielding the processor here and there like you are saying you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior of `process.nextTick` has changed since the question was asked. The previous answers also did not follow the question as per the cleanliness and efficiency of the function.

```
// in node 0.9.0, process.nextTick fired before IO events, but setImmediate did
// not yet exist. before 0.9.0, process.nextTick between IO events, and after
// 0.9.0 it fired before IO events. if setImmediate and process.nextTick are
// both missing fall back to the tick shim.
var tick =
  (root.process && process.versions && process.versions.node === '0.9.0') ?
  tickShim :
  (root.setImmediate || (root.process && process.nextTick) || tickShim);

function tickShim(fn) {setTimeout(fn, 1);}

// executes the iter function for the first object key immediately, can be
// tweaked to instead defer immediately
function asyncForEach(object, iter) {
  var keys = Object.keys(object), offset = 0;

  (function next() {
    // invoke the iterator function
    iter.call(object, keys[offset], object[keys[offset]], object);

    if (++offset < keys.length) {
      tick(next);
    }
  })();
}
```

Do take note of [@alessioalex's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002817/345645) regarding Kue and proper job queueing.

See also: [share-time](https://github.com/skeggse/share-time), a module I wrote to do something similar to the intent of the original question.

Comment: Nice to see this question revisited with the latest info. process.setImmediate vs process.nextTick is an important distinction. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Jesse! Note that it's `setImmediate`, like `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, not `process.setImmediate`. In the code snippet, I use `root.setImmediate` to avoid a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Whoops! need to drink my coffee this morning!

Answer (score 2):

There are many things to be said here.

- If you have a web application for example, you wouldn't want to do "heavy lifting" in that application's process. Even though your algorithm is efficient, it would still most probably slow down the app.
- Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you would probably use one of the following approaches:
  a) put your "for in" loop in a child process and get the result in your main app once it's over
  b) if you are trying to achieve something like delayed jobs (for ex sending emails) you should try https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue
  c) make a Kue-like program of your own using Redis to communicate between the main app and the "heavy lifting" app.

For these approaches you could also use multiple processes (for concurrency).

Now time for a sample code (it may not be perfect, so if you have a better suggestion please correct me):

```
var forIn, obj;

// the "for in" loop
forIn = function(obj, callback){
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  (function iterate(keys) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      callback(keys[0], obj[keys[0]]);
      return ((keys = keys.slice(1)).length && iterate(keys));
    });
  })(keys);
};

// example usage of forIn
// console.log the key-val pair in the callback
function start_processing_the_big_object(my_object) {
  forIn(my_object, function (key, val) { console.log("key: %s; val: %s;", key, val); });
}

// Let's simulate a big object here
// and call the function above once the object is created
obj = {};
(function test(obj, i) {
  obj[i--] = "blah_blah_" + i;
  if (!i) { start_processing_the_big_object(obj); }
  return (i && process.nextTick(function() { test(obj, i); }));
})(obj, 30000);
```

Comment: I would be worried about all of the array slicing that's going on.  Did you benchmark this?

Comment: Didn't benchmark it, but you could definitely go around slicing and use a different technique instead (keeping the same idea).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
  doSomething(i);
  }
```

do something like this:

```
var i = 0, limit;
while (i < len) {
  limit = (i+100);
  if (limit > len)
    limit = len;
  process.nextTick(function(){
     for (; i<limit; i++) {
      doSomething(i);
     }
    });
  }
}
```

This will run 100 iterations of the loop, then return control to the system for a moment, then pick up where it left off, till its done.

Edit:  here it is adapted for your particular case (and with the number of iterations it performs at a time passed in as an argument):

```
var forin = function(obj, callback, numPerChunk){
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var len = keys.length;
  var i = 0, limit;
  while (i < len) {
    limit = i + numPerChunk;
    if (limit > len)
      limit = len;
    process.nextTick(function(){
        for (; i<limit; i++) {
          callback(keys[i], obj[keys[i]], obj);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you actually test this?  All of the work will get done in the first `nextTick`, thus yielding exactly once regardless of the number of iterations.

Answer (score -1):

The following applies to [browser] JavaScript; it may be entirely irrelevant to node.js.

---

Two options I know of:

1. Use multiple timers to process the queue. They will interleave which will give the net effect of "processing items more often" (this is also a good way to steal more CPU ;-), or,
2. Do more work per cycle, either count or time based.

I am not sure if Web Workers are applicable/available.

Happy coding.